# How can I send a wxTextCtrl input to a wxListBox in wxLua?

Tags: lua, wxwidgets, wxlua

I'm pretty new to both Lua and wxWidgets, and currently I am trying to show my input from a wxTextCtrl to my wxListBox by pressing a button. How can I do this same code but using wxLua instead of C++?

```
listPlayers->AppendString(txtUserInput->GetValue())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listPlayers:AppendString(txtUserInput:GetValue())
```

Do yourself a favour and learn the very basics of Lua befor you continue using wxLua.